# Is there a Linux/Unix equivalent for the Windows KTM and Transactional NTFS?

Tags: linux, unix, transactions, linux-kernel

Windows, for some time, has supported transactional interactions with files - using the [Kernel Transaction Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_Transaction_Manager) ([MS KTM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366273(v=vs.85).aspx)) and [Transactional NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_NTFS).  These features facilitate transactional changes to files on a local file system.

Does Linux/Unix have equivalent features?  Are there any published performance comparisons?

Comment: I suggest you migrate this question to http://unix.stackexchange.com/ as this is off-topic here

Comment: My question is about programming APIs and OS support for them.  To me, this suggests a question for StackOverflow more than unix.stackexchange.com - unless questions about writing reliable software,  targetting Linux/Unix, is now considered off topic on StackOverflow?

Comment: Well, maybe not exactly what you are looking for, but ZFS may offer transactions in a way that suits your needs.

Comment: I am (vaguely) familiar with ZFS, but I am not aware of an API that will allow me to ensure, from within an application, that either N writes to file(s) all succeed, or are all rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a clear answer for you on this, but ACID based File System discussions have been going on in the Linux world for a long time.

Perhaps you can catch up with Richard Spillane, an author on multiple papers regarding the subject:
    [Amino PDF](http://www.fsl.cs.stonybrook.edu/docs/amino-tos06/amino.pdf) 
    [Enabling Transactional File Access via Lightweight Kernel Extensions](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/fast09/tech/full_papers/spillane/spillane.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the interesting pointers.  I've up-voted your answer, but did not award the bounty as - perhaps - it is not 'the answer'.  The absence of a specific, equivalent, technology suggests that there is no existing Linux (or other Unix) equivalent... but stops short of making that explicit claim.  I still find this surprising - though my research has led to a similar apparent dead end.

Comment: both are prototype. Do I understand correctly that there's no real usable alternative for Linux today?